# AdditionalData in OneSignal Push Notification

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, onesignal

Hi guys I'm developing Multiplatform app with Xamarin and I'm using OneSignal platform for push notification.

Here's the code for sending push in post:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");

            Dictionary<string, object> userData = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "app_id", "MyAppID" },
                {"channel_for_external_user_ids", "push" },
                { "include_external_user_ids", new string[] { $"MyID" } },
                {"contents", new  {en = "Are you ok?" } },
                {"headings", new  {en = "Ehi" } },
                {"data", new {FromID = 1234} },
                {"priority", 10 },
            };
```

Notification is sent without any problem. In my Xamarin app I try to detect "data", and here's the issue.

```
        private static void HandleNotificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result)
    {

        try
        {
            //Notification data
            OSNotificationPayload payload = result.notification.payload;

            Dictionary<string, object> additionalData = payload.additionalData;

            int NotificationFromID = 0;

            if (additionalData != null)
            {
                if (additionalData.ContainsKey("FromID"))
                {
                    NotificationFromID = (int)additionalData["FromID"]);
                }
            }

            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        

    }
```

I got error System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

I tried everything: Convert.ToInt32, I tried to pass a string... but nothing works.

If I do something like that

```
Debug.WriteLine(additionalData["FromID"].GetType());
```

I got Foundation.NSNumber (if I try to pass a string) or Foundation.NSString (if I try to pass a string). I guess NSNumber and NSString are iOS objects

How can I solve this?
I just need to pass an integer value

thanks

Comment: Hi, it seems can not get `FromID` from `additionalData["FromID"]` directly. You'd better get `data` from `additionalData` frist, then can get `FromID` from it. You could have a try. And if it is a type of `NSNumber`, you coudl use `(int)NSNumberObject` to convert it.

Comment: From documentation, it seems additionalData is Dictionary<string, object> so I cannot change this. The issue is I can't convert object in any way.  For the moment I solved with a workaround (I'm using param "url" that is a string, and I can easily convert) but I know it's not the right approach

Comment: Hi, which line will occur this error? I have tried in my local site, `if (additionalData.ContainsKey("FromID"))` this line code return `false`, therefore `NotificationFromID = (int)additionalData["FromID"]);` this line code can not be invoked.